# Rewrite part of a c/c++ program in python

Tags: python, c++, c, blender

I am trying to develop a plugin interface in python for a popular 3d program, called Blender 3D. The purpose of the plugin interface is to extend some functionality of the program through python.

Now my problem is that I am trying to asses the performance impact. I will replace an existing functionality written in c code with something written in python.

I am worried that this might slow the application because the functionality that I am replacing is executed in real time and has to be really fast. It consists of a plain c function that just splits some polygons in triangles.

So the operations that I executing work on pieces of data that usually do not have more than 30 or 40 input points. And at most the operations that I am executing on them have a complexity of log(n) * n^2.

But I will be creating plenty of python objects each second, so I am already prepared to implement pooling to recycle the objects.

Now I am mostly worried that the python code will run 100 times slower than the c code and slow down the application. Should I be worried?

At most I will be doing 8500 computations in a single python function call. This function will be called each time when rendering the application interface.

Comment: Did you look at `ctype`? You could just create your objects in Python and do your calculation with your C code. There are some tricks to pass Python object to a C programm, but if you're familiar with C it should be "easy"

Comment: The usual way to solve these worries is profiling: see if the c++ parts you want to replace take a large chunk of the execution time. If not, then replacing them with Python won't be too costly. And, because you have the profiling time for the C++ parts, you could measure each new Python function/method/stanza and compare its running time to the equivalent C++ running time.

Comment: That being said, you will be slower in Python, but I have no idea how much, as it depends on your application. `numpy` (and others) works pretty fast because it has a lot of function implemented in C.

Comment: @HarryPotfleur Also some parts are implemented in Fortran (c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of using c or python will depend on the use of your work. Is this a function that the blender developers will accept into the blender development? Do you expect many blender users will want to use it? A python addon allows you to develop your work outside of the main blender development and give many users access to it, while a patch to the c code that requires the user to compile their own version will reduce users.

You could also look at compiling your c code to a binary library that is included with the python addon and loaded as a python module. See two addons by Pyroevil created using [cython](http://cython.org/) - [molecular](https://github.com/Pyroevil/Blender-Molecular-Script.git) and [cubesurfer](https://github.com/Pyroevil/CubeSurfer.git), some pre-built binaries are available on his [main website](http://pyroevil.com/cubesurfer-addon-download/). I'm not sure if using cython makes the python module creation easier or not, you could also use cython only as glue between python and your library.